# How to add labels onto segments of a circle in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I’m working on a project with p5.js where I draw a circle, draw arcs (straight red lines) to separate the circle then another arc between each of the red lines (blue lines). The idea looks like the included image below:

[image: current figure]

What I'm confused about is how to position the labels in the circle drawing so that they're positioned in each segment inside the circle but outside the blue arcs. My question is how do I add text labels to this figure so that it looks like the image below?

[image: desired image]

Here is the shortened code to produce the first image (circle without the labels) so far:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  let startX = 50;
  let startY = 50;
  
  let data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  let width = 80;
  let angle = -Math.PI / 2;
  let radianPer = Math.PI * 2 / Object.keys(data).length;

  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  ellipse(startX, startY, width, width);
  Object.keys(data).forEach(i => {
      fill(255);
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      arc(startX, startY, width, width, angle, angle + radianPer, PIE);
      fill(255);

      stroke(0, 0, 255);
      arc(startX, startY, width / 2, width / 2, angle, angle + radianPer, PIE);
      angle += radianPer;
    
      // add label here
  });
}
```

Edit (02/05/22): updated code to match the screenshot image example.

Comment: I could not run your code because you are missing semicolons to close the lines.

Comment: @KamielDev I added the semicolons. As a side note, this is the code that would be inside p5's draw() function. I didn't add setup() or draw() here in the interest of saving space.

Comment: I think it would help if you posted a runnable example, and that would include setup() and draw().  We should be able to copy/paste the source code into the p5.js web editor and have it run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying a label in the middle of a segment of an arc involves using the angle for the middle of that arc with the sine and cosine functions to find the X and Y coordinates. For more information see the [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) article on wikipedia.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  // Text settings
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  let startX = 50;
  let startY = 50;

  let data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  let width = 80;
  let angle = -Math.PI / 2;
  let radianPer = (Math.PI * 2) / Object.keys(data).length;

  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  ellipse(startX, startY, width, width);
  Object.keys(data).forEach((i) => {
    fill(255);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    arc(startX, startY, width, width, angle, angle + radianPer, PIE);
    fill(255);

    stroke(0, 0, 255);
    arc(startX, startY, width / 2, width / 2, angle, angle + radianPer, PIE);

    // add label here
    let textAngle = angle + radianPer / 2;

    // Use sine and cosine to determine the position for the text
    // Since sine is opposite / hypotenuse, taking the sine of the angle and
    // multiplying by distance gives us the vertical offset (i.e. the Y
    // coordinate).
    // Likewise with cosine for the X coordinate
    noStroke();
    fill(0);
    text(
      data[i].toString(),
      startX + cos(textAngle) * width / 2 * 0.75,
      startY + sin(textAngle) * width / 2 * 0.75
    );

    // Don't update angle until after calculating the angle for the label
    angle += radianPer;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! My bad about the code not matching the image — I meant it to be more of a illustrative example since the arc lines aren't obvious with the image that the code produces, but I see that's caused some confusion. Code has been updated to match the images now.

Comment: I updated my answer to match your code.